# How To retrieve value of an element from same name multiple elements in XML through xQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have and xml field like this in sql server

```
<propertyDetail>
  <importID>1735532</importID>
  <pincode />
  <landmarks />
  <features>
    <feature>Society  Name: sec-87 srs peral  floor faridabad</feature>
    <feature>Transaction: Resale Property</feature>
    <feature>Possession: Dec,2011</feature>
    <feature>*Ownership: Freehold*</feature>
    <feature>Age of Property: Under Construction</feature>
  </features>
</propertyDetail>
```

I want to retrieve the feature which has value "**Ownership: Freehold**" through xQuery and sequence of features may vary.

Welcome any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `@x` is your xml

```
select @x.query('//feature[. = "*Ownership: Freehold*"]')
```

If you want to find anything that starts with Ownership then

```
select @x.query('//feature[substring(.,1,9)="Ownership"]')
```

(but ideally you should improve your XML structure, if you can)

Comment: Thanks @podiluska its working. But what if I want Feature containing Ownership? I mean in my case ownership value  may be 'freehold' or 'lease' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of that feature in a filter expression, i.e.:

```
//propertyDetail[features/feature[. eq "*Ownership: Freehold*"]]
```